# How to add data from a form into a database with Django

Tags: python, django, database, forms, http

I'm trying to add some data into my database, using a form, made with Django.

The model:

```
class Image(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/", null=True, blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)
    album = models.ForeignKey('Album', null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    visible = models.BooleanField(blank=False, null=False, default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

As you can see, the model has more attributes then I try to upload for the moment, just for testing purposes.

the view:

```
def create(request):
if request.POST:
    form = ImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        name = form.cleaned_data['name']
        dexcription = form.cleaned_data['description']
        visible = form.cleaned_data['visible']
        image = Image.objects.create(
            name = name,
            description = description,
            visible = visible,
        )




        #form.save()

        #return render_to_response('imageall.html',context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/index/')

else:
    form = ImageForm()

args = {}
args.update(csrf(request))

args['form'] = form

return render_to_response('create_image.html', args, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

You can see I've been fiddling around with the "save" part of the view.
I guess `form.save()` would be the easiest way, but that does'nt work either.

and ofcourse the form:

```
from django import forms
from forpix.models import Image
from forpix.models import Album
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class ImageForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Image
        fields = ('name', 'description', 'visible')
```

the main urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'mysite.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),

    url(r'^accounts/login/$', 'mysite.views.login'),
    url(r'^accounts/auth/$', 'mysite.views.auth_view'),
    url(r'^accounts/logout/$', 'mysite.views.logout'),
    url(r'^accounts/loggedin/$', 'mysite.views.loggedin'),
    url(r'^accounts/invalid/$', 'mysite.views.invalid_login'),
    url(r'^accounts/register/$', 'mysite.views.register_user'),
    url(r'^accounts/register_success/$', 'mysite.views.register_success'),

    url(r'^image/(?P<image_id>\d+)/$', 'forpix.views.showimage', name='image_url'),

    url(r'^create/$', 'forpix.views.create'),
    url(r'^$', 'forpix.views.index'),
    url(r'^index/$', 'forpix.views.index'),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

and the urls.py of the app

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'mysite.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),

    url(r'^(?P<image_id>\d+)/$', views.results, name='results'),

    )
```

Now if I test things out, I can see and fill in the form.
When I submit, the terminal shows a http message

```
"POST /index/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3552
```

The page redirects to my index page, but when i look into my database, nothing was added.

Can please someone explain me what i did wrong?

I'm using Python 3.4
I'm on Win7
and the database is an sqllite I guess

Comment: there is a typo in the code in the post: dexcription instead of description - I am surprised that this does not throw an error unless the typo is only in your post - can you correct it in this case

Comment: How are you checking your db?

Comment: @ger.s.brett Fixed the typo, but it doesn't change a thing.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Through the admin pages in my browser.

Comment: It seems like you're posting to `/index/` though. Is that the URL for the "create" view? Maybe you should show your urls.py.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I added the urls.py. ALready thanks for looking into it.

Comment: So as I say, you seem to be posting to /index/ not /create/. That's presumably in the form tag in your create_image.html template itself.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I found it. the `action="..."` in my template, like you suggested was incorrectly filled in. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

Could you print the `form.error()` This will print the error to your terminal, and I'm assuming your code is properly indented in your IDE, as it is not here. The form only save when if the form is valid `form.is_valid()`, and you didn't put any return for when it's not valid.

```
def create(request):
    if request.POST:
         form = ImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
         if form.is_valid():
             name = form.cleaned_data['name']
             description = form.cleaned_data['description']
             visible = form.cleaned_data['visible']
             image = Image.objects.create(
                      name = name,
                      description = description,
                      visible = visible,
                        )
             form.save()
             return HttpResponseRedirect('/index/')
         else:
             print(form.error())

             

    else:
       form = ImageForm()


       return render_to_response('create_image.html', args, 
                 context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```